# Using input type file in the anchor tag for a dropdown-item using bootstrap4

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the input type file in one of my drop down item which is in the anchor tag.

```html
<a className="dropdown-item" href='#'>
<i className="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 upload-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload Resume</a>
<input type='file' title=" " onChange={(e) => { props.uploadResumeFolder(e, item.id, item.jdName) }} directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" allowdirs="" multiple />
```

So, Now here after this there are multiple options for that dropdown, but here if I add this options then the next one is getting clicked on this.
Because I don't want that option like No File Choosen to show users.

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
<div className="dropdown-item">
    <label for="fileUpload">
        <i className="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 upload-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload Resume</label>
    <input id="fileUpload" type='file' title=" "
    style="display: none;" 
    onChange={(e)=> { props.uploadResumeFolder(e, item.id, item.jdName) }} directory=""
    webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" allowdirs="" multiple />
</div>
```

`<a>` has been replaced with `<div>`. `<input>` tag has been made hidden. But if you click on `<label>`, it will open file upload window because the `<label>` has `for` attribute. Hope it will help you.

You can use `<a>` tag instead of `<div>` that I replaced.